# How to clear facebook share image cache for entire site

Tags: facebook, caching, share

I have cleared facebook cache to change "share image" by using 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug for specific URL.

I want to clear cache and change "share image" for entire site. There are hundreds of URL, so it is tough to clear cache for each url by entering here
 https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Also I use http://www.webcoachbd.com?fbrefresh=5465468464 this in above debugger. Yet not appearing correct image when share in facebook for many URL in this site (webcoachbd.com).

somebody help plz.